# PDFkit gem table of contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

Using version 0.8.2 of the [PDFKit gem](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit), passing in `toc` as indicated in the [docs](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) throws an error:

```
format.pdf {
    html = render_to_string(:action => 'pdf.html.haml')
    kit  = PDFKit.new(html, {toc: true})
    send_data kit.to_pdf, :filename => "thing.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf'
  }
```

The generic error, which I'm showing so you can see that `toc` is being passed as `wkhtmltopdf` requires, and as the [specs of the PDFkit gem](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=toc%3A%20) suggest, without the `--`:

```
command failed (exitstatus=0): /Users/Emma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 toc - -
```

Comment: you should do `render_to_string(action: "users/pdf_gen")` for `users controller pdf_gen method` not haml file

Comment: Thanks, and sure, done that, but didn't fix this particular error.

Comment: `kit = PDFKit.new("my name", toc => "")` is working fine I do no  need `{}` and `true` for `toc`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
format.pdf {
    html = render_to_string(:action => '<controller_name>/action_name')
    kit  = PDFKit.new(html.to_s, toc: '')
    send_data kit.to_pdf, :filename => "thing.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf'
  }
```

Comment: Maybe it's my version of the binary. It's not working for me but good to know it's OK for you -- and thanks for the response.

Comment: yep, and in production it's no better.

Comment: ahh got may be what is the versio of the gem PDFkit you are using ? do not use 0.6.1 version https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/228 here it is explained. please use 0.6.2. Please let me know